# .htaccess redirect with folder and file exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to only redirect http://www.website.com/ to https://www.newsite.com.br/website

Except all files and directories like:

http://www.website.com/admin
http://www.website.com/img/image.png
http://www.website.com/cliente

And any URL different then http://www.website.com/ should not redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.newsite.com.br/website/ [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: but I want that any URL different then http://www.website.com/ should work, I just give a few examples.., is possible?

Comment: ok so if only `http://www.website.com/` needs to be redirected then we don't even need exceptions. Check my updated rule now.